# Which function in code has bug and how to fix the code to work properly again

Tags: javascript, logic

The function below cannot be run because it has a bug which function has a bug and how to  fix the code  to work properly again

```js
function fn(input) {
  let pair = {
    "}": "{",
    ")": "(",
    "]": "[",
  };
  const start_pair = Object.values(pair);
  const end_pair = Object.keys(pair);
  let temp = [];
  for (const i of input) {
    if (start_pair.indexOf(i) != -1) {
      temp.push(i);
      console.log(temp)
    }
    let top;
    if (end_pair.indexOf(i) != -1) {
      console.log(top)
      top = temp.pop();
    }
    return temp.length == 0;
  }
}

  const input = ['}','​{','(','['];
  fn(input)
```

The result is

```
undefined
[ '(' ]
[ '(', '[' ]
```

Why i got undefined when I put '}' at the first of index

Comment: What's your input and expected output? Welcome to SO btw. You might find reading the site [help section](https://stackoverflow.com/help) useful when it comes to [asking a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and this [question checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist). Code that you've worked on to solve the problem should include a [mcve].

Comment: I made you a snippet. Please add relevant code to it to give us a [mcve]

Comment: One thing - You need to NOT return until you have looped over the complete string

Comment: [Many examples](https://www.google.com/search?q=javascript+validate+string+brackets+OR+braces+match+site%3Astackoverflow.com)

Answer (score 0):

Your top is undefined if temp is empty and you return too soon

```js
function fn(input) {
  let pair = {
    "}": "{",
    ")": "(",
    "]": "[",
  };
  const start_pair = Object.values(pair);
  const end_pair = Object.keys(pair);
  let temp = [];
  for (const i of input) {
    if (start_pair.indexOf(i) != -1) {
      temp.push(i);
      console.log(temp)
    }
    let top;
    if (end_pair.indexOf(i) != -1) {
      if (temp.length > 0) {
        top = temp.pop();
        console.log(top)
      }
    }
  }
  return temp.length == 0;

}

const input = ['}', '​{', '(', '['];
console.log(fn(input))
```

Comment: I am not sure which function in this code has a bug. Can you suggest for improving my code

Comment: `Your top is undefined if temp is empty and you return too soon`